# Dual displays detected as singular display via usb c dock issue (MBP 2017, Dell)

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

**Hardware**

- 1 MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- 2 Dell
  U2517D
  [documentation](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-u2518d-monitor/manuals)
- 1 Hubee usb-c dock [documentation](http://www.urban-factory.com/en/home/855-hubee-docking-station-3760170858371.html)

**Expectation**

Successfully connect and extend both of my Dell "U2517D" monitors using my "Hubee" usb-c dock to my MacBook Pro to render 3 separate windows(Mbp screen included).

**Issue**

The usb-c dock has a DP cable(connected to one of the dell monitors) and a HDMI cable(connected to one of the dell monitors) plugged into it [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C1vd.jpg), this allows both monitors to operate however they only seem to render a singular mirrored display output [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hxqX.jpg). In display preferences this is what I see [picture](https://imgur.com/a/XA1Q2). I have attempted to daisy chain both monitors together then doing a single DP connection to the dock but it didn't work. I have also tried pressing the detect monitors button in the display preferences but it has not worked.

Answer (score 4):

What you ask is simply not possible with that hardware.

Due to the way the signal must be demultiplexed, you will need a Thunderbolt 3 dock instead of a USB-C dock to be able to drive the two external displays with separate content.

Alternatively you can connect one of the monitors directly to the MacBook Pro using a standard USB-C to DisplayPort cable.

Comment: Both are correct. Thunderbolt 3 dock or one with built-in DisplayLink. Some background on why a "normal" USB-C dock doesn't work: https://sebvance.medium.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-macbook-pros-and-their-lack-of-displayport-mst-multi-stream-98ce33d64af4

Answer (score 3):

Unlike what jksoegaard says, in my experience, running dual screens of a single USB-C works fine depending on the dock. Both the Lenovo USB-C dock and the Dell D6000 both support running dual 1920x1080 displays. The Dell D6000 will even support 1440p monitors. You'll need to install the Display Link drivers manually though, available here: https://www.displaylink.com

Answer (score 1):

Ιt seems macbooks can not function properly (at least not with HP G5 docking station and not without the multiple external monitors been detected as **one**) with only one usb-c cable connected.

I used one cable to the docking station and another one HDMI to usb-c.

So it worked with 2 cables on 2 usb-c ports.

I really wonder why much cheaper laptops work great just with one cable to this docking station.

My setup: Macbook pro 16", 2019, 2x27 HP Monitors, HP G5 docking station.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Macbook Pro. The solution to add an external adapter to the mac works but it's annoying as i need to connect the adapter all the time which is prone to heating and it could break the port with any light hit. It's surprising how "UnPro" this "Pro" machine while as you mentioned, the cheapest laptop from other competitors will provide duel screening easily and have more that just USB C inputs.

Comment: @Ali123 I asked at an Apple Store and they told me the monitors must have Thunderbolt 3. Then with a proper docking station (no idea which that is) you can connect up to 5 monitors or something..